# chemmacros \iupac command shows no formatting in titles

Tags: formatting, titles, chemmacros, section-titles

i googled the problem and found that apparently nobody had issues with this before... I want to use compound names set up with the \iupac command of chemmacros in titles.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
  \section{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
   \subsection{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
    \subsubsection{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
     \paragraph{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
      \subparagraph{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
       \iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}
\end{document}
```

leaves me with this:

[image: output \iupac in titles]

Any way to activate the formatting in the title or do I have to let go of the \iupac command? I need the "trans" and the "N"s in italics.

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` probably (assuming that you still want them in sans serif).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get a warning, namely

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmss/bx/it' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmss/bx/n' instead on input line 7.
```

which means that sans serif boldface italic is not available with Computer Modern Sans.

You can switch to Latin Modern with `\usepackage{lmodern}` or to T1 encoding with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

You may also want to load `textgreek`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usechemmodule{all}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}

\begin{document}
 \chapter{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
  \section{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
   \subsection{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
    \subsubsection{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
     \paragraph{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
      \subparagraph{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
       \iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For Times, you can adjust `textgreek` to use Tempora, but don't use `mathptmx`, which is basically a big kludge.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usechemmodule{all}
\chemsetup{greek=textgreek}

\renewcommand*{\textgreekfontmap}{
   {qhv/b/*}{LGR/cmss/bx/*}
   {qhv/*/*}{LGR/cmss/*/*}
   {*/*/*}{LGR/Tempora-TLF/*/*}}


\begin{document}
 \chapter{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
  \section{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
   \subsection{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
    \subsubsection{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
     \paragraph{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
      \subparagraph{\iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}}
       \iupac{\trans-\N,\N'-\a-testo-weirdamide}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that warning. I am using "mathptmx", which I omitted in the MWE. But the problem stays the same. Seems like I have to switch to the "boring" lmodern. Thank you for the swift answer!

Comment: @bfalk I added how to get a Times-like font.

Comment: Thank you very much for the addition. I will check it out when I have more time. For the first try in my large document, I suddenly get the error that "\nhex" is already defined. Which is a command that I defined as a shortcut for myself, could it be added by those packages?